# Transit Visa requirement in Belgrade and Abu Dhabi

Tags: visas, indian-citizens, paperwork, german-citizens

A friend and I are travelling from Germany to India. This is the first time we are travelling with layovers. I hold an Indian passport with residence permit in Germany. My friend has a German passport. Our flight has a layover at Belgrade Nikola Tesla (BEG) and Abu Dhabi International (AUH).

Do we need transit visas for either of these?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Source: TIMATIC, the database used by airlines.

None of you need a visa to transit at either Belgrade or Abu Dhabi.

Even if having to pick up luggage, both of you can enter both Serbia and the UAE. Your friend needs their passport, and you need your passport and German residence card.

So you're all good.